# A basic question regarding zeros of rational functions with several variables.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $f$ be rational function with $n$ variables, say
$$
f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\frac{P(x_1,\ldots,x_n)}{Q(x_1,\ldots,x_n)}
$$
where $P,Q$ are polynomials. In addition, suppose that $P,Q$ are **not** constant functions and that $P\nmid Q$ (as polynomials over $\mathbb C$). Must $f$ have a zero over the complex field $\mathbb C$? that is, a tuple $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ such that $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=0$? I know that by the fundamental Theorem of algebra, the assertion is true when $n=1$. Is it true for any $n$?

Comment: Why is it true if $n=1$? What about $f(x)=1/x$?

Comment: You right. I need to demand $P\nmid Q$ (as polynomials over $\mathbb C$) - see Edit. Thanks @Zuy.

Comment: In that case it is true. You can show that if $p$ is a divisor of $P$ (which by assumption exists), then it has a zero which is not a zero of $Q$, unless $p$ also divides $Q$. Stuff like this is treated in Algebraic Geometry.

Comment: Thanks @Zuy, but why P has a (non trivial) divisor?

Comment: @bosz Since $P$ is assumed non-constant.

Comment: @Zuy Not true. $P$ being non-constant does not necessarily imply that $P$ has a non-trivial divisor. For example, $y^2-x^3-1$ (non-singular of genus 1) is irreducible over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @ShyamalSayak All I am saying is that any non-constant polynomial will have some irreducible factor, which is also the case for $y^2-x^3-1$.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn’t have to be non-trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true. If $P$ is non-constant and $P$ and $Q$ share no common irreducible factor, then the set of zeros of $P$ is infinite and there is a maximal ideal $(x_1-a_1,\ldots,x_n-a_n)$ (in fact all the maximal ideals must be of this form by *weak Nullstellensatz*) in $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ such that $P\in (x_1-a_1,\ldots,x_n-a_n)$ but $Q\not\in (x_1-a_1,\ldots,x_n-a_n)$. Thus $f(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=0$.

Comment: No, the number of solutions to $P=Q=0$ can be non-finite. Take for instance $n=3$ and $P=x_1$, $Q=x_2$.

Comment: @KReiser Yes. You are right. That works only when $n=2$.

Comment: Thanks @ShyamalSayak. So your proof only true for $n=2$?

Comment: I have edited it. It is true in general.